# Outliers are missing when using plotrix boxplot() in R

Tags: r, boxplot, plotrix

Instead of R's own `boxplot()` the outliers are missing when using `gap.boxplot()` from the `plotrix` package. I try to understand why.

See this example please:

```
> mtcars[2,c('mpg')] <- 45
> mtcars[6,c('mpg')] <- 77
```

Using `boxplot(mtcars$mpg)` you can see two extra dots (the outliers) on top of the boxplot.

[image: R's own <code>boxplot()</code>]

Using `gap.boxplot(mtcars$mpg)` from `plotrix` package result in that graphic

[image]

The big question is why and how to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible that they are there, just coloured white for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround to get the outliers. It involves accessing the value of outliers from the `gap.boxplot` command. Looks like the value of outliers are being computed but not plotted. I am curious to find out why it is happening.

```
gap.boxplot(mtcars$mpg)
outliers = gap.boxplot(mtcars$mpg)$out
points(x = rep(1,length(outliers)), y = c(outliers))
```

Comment: Good job with the workaround. This looks like a bug to me: I would suggest/encourage contacting the maintainer (`maintainer("plotrix")`) and letting them know

Comment: The maintainer is informed and he offered new code. It will be fixed in the next update.